# Semantic UI customize ui.menu background color

Tags: css, less, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to customize semantic ui using it's theming feature.

I'm using semantic-ui-react.

I defined my menu css override in 
`/semantic/src/site/collections/menu.overrides` as following:

```
.ui.menu.item {
  color: fade(#eb6510, 80%); !important;
  background: black !important;
}
```

My Menu component is simple:

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to="/" name="logo" activeclassname="active"/>
  <Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to="/menu"  name="Menu" activeclassname="active"/>
    <Menu.Menu position="right">
      <Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to="/login" name="Log in" activeclassname="active"/>
      <Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to="/register" name="Sign up" activeclassname="active"/>
   </Menu.Menu>
</Menu>
```

but it still renders as default theme: 
[image]

Here's the screenshot of element inspection: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I probably need to define more specificity for `active` class and `right` class but shouldn't the 'logo' item be rendered according to my less code?

I can still change menu.variables to change the background color (eg; `@itemBackground: fade(#eb6510, 80%);` ), but I really want to use pure css to override default CSS in case I want to migrate out from Semantic UI in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing content inside of your `semantic-ui` theme variables and overrides, you have to build new styles. Simply changing the overrides is not going to do it. Right now `semantic-ui-react` is agnostic to the css. It just renders the markup and classes that are needed. If you have installed `semantic-ui` as well as `semantic-ui-react` in your project, you will need to run some of the `gulp` scripts in the build tools. Take a look here: https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html#gulp-commands